# How to create and access several datasets in pyQt5 GUI on python?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

I have some trouble with my PyQt5 GUI code. What I would like to do is asking the user for a file using the actionLoad_file menu. I would like then to import the datasets using my LoadFile function located in another file. The issue is that I don't know how to assign the name of the file selected by the user to the dataframe generated by my LoadFile function. The goal is to allows several importations and generating a dataframe for each click.
In addition, I don't know how to access to my dataframe in another method (plotting for example).

I hope I was clear... Thanks in advance for you help.
Here is the main function

```
import sys
import tkinter
import os.path
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import matplotlib
from load_function import LoadFile #Importing homemade functions
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class gui_main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(gui_main, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('GUI.ui', self)$
    self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.plotting)
    self.actionLoad_file.triggered.connect(self.load_file_method)
    self.show()

def load_file_method(self):
    tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
    filepath = askopenfilename()
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    file,extension = filename.rsplit('.')
    vars()[file] = LoadFile(filepath)
    gui_main.list_loaded_file.addItem(filename)

def plotting(self):
     plt.scatter(file.data["x"],file.data["y"])
     plt.show()
```

And here is the LoadFile function :

```
import pandas
from sklearn import preprocessing

class LoadFile:
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.data = pandas.read_csv(open(file), delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a `tkinter` file dialog when `Qt` has a perfectly serviceable file dialog built in.

Anyway, as I understand the question, you want to be able to read multiple files, create data frames from the data in these files and store the file names in what I assume is a `QListWidget` named `list_loaded_file`. You then want to be able to select a file in this list and plot the corresponding data. If this is indeed what you want then you could just add the data frame as data to the list widget items when adding them to the list widget via `item.setData(role, data)`, where `role` is some integer >= `QtCore.Qt.UserRole`. This data frame can then later be retrieved via `item.data(role)`.

Here is how this could look like for your example. In this example, pressing the plot button will plot the data for the first selected item in the list.

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from load_function import LoadFile


class gui_main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    # role for storing the data frames in the items
    USERDATA_ROLE = QtCore.Qt.UserRole

    def __init__(self):
        # the same as before

    def load_file_method(self):
        # I'm using a QFileDialog to get the file path
        filepath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if not filepath:
            return
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

        # read data and create data frame
        dataframe = LoadFile(filepath)

        # create list widget item and store data in item
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(filename)
        item.setData(self.USERDATA_ROLE, dataframe)
        self.list_view.addItem(item)

    def plotting(self):
        # select first selected item in file list.
        items = self.list_view.selectedItems()
        if not items:
            return
        item = items[0]
 
        # retrieve and plot data
        data = item.data(self.USERDATA_ROLE)
        plt.scatter(data["x"], data["y"])
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main = gui_main()
    main.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is perfectly what I was waiting for. Now it's working well!!! :)

Comment: Hey, I have another short question if possible... For the plotting, I'm filtering some data when the user asks for specific parameters in an If loop. However, it appears that when I want to load the original data, they are modified according to the parameter... Is there a memory effect in the data stored in the list? I've tried to copy than to have an original set but they are still modified... Thanks in advance for your answer. Best regards,

Comment: I've just resolve that problem :) I copy the datas from the item in a temporary variable in order to avoid them to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this (in my case just loads a .ini file) to put in your `MainWindow`, and store `filename` in there with `self`, using actual PyQt5:

```
BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

def readFile(self):  # ? Open
    """Restores GUI user input from a config file"""
    #* File dialog
    self.filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self,
        "Select a configuration file to load…",
        BASEDIR,
        'Configuration Files (*.ini)',
        options=qtw.QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks
    )
    #* Invalid file or none
    if self.filename == "":
        qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
            self, "Operation aborted", "Empty filename or none selected. \n Please try again.",
            qtw.QMessageBox.Ok
        )
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Select a valid configuration file")
    #* Valid file
    else:
        if self.filename.lower().endswith('.ini'):
            try:
                <...> # your code

            except Exception or TypeError as e:
                qtw.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', f"Could not open settings: {e}")
        else:
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
                self, "Invalid file type", "Please select a .ini file.", qtw.QMessageBox.Ok
            )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer. I'm pretty new in python programming. Can you explain me a bit more your code, please? What is Qwt? Can you describe the self.filename, _  variable. the _ is for storing the name of the file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: qtw is an alias for QtWidgets when you import it. You can type: `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw`. You add `self.` in front of `filename` to store it as that class' variable and access it outside the `readFile` method. The underscore saves the extension that `getOpenFileName` returns, but it's not meant to be used in my code so the underscore is by convention the name for discarded variables.

Comment: Ok its clearer for me now :) I understand that I can access the filename in another method by calling it self.filename. But if I load two file with my function, x and y for example. I would like to know how can I access then in another method.. When I try self.x or self.y it's not working. Probably because the variable name still filename? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to load more than one file at the same time, use `getOpenFileNames` instead, which will return a list of filenames you can access by their indexes.